# Puppetserver install fails on Debian 11 Bullseye "Depends: puppet-agent (>= 6.16.0) but it is not installable"

Tags: debian, puppet

trying to install Puppet Server on Debian 11 Bullseye by following descriptions

- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/install_puppet.html#enable_the_puppet_platform_repository
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/server/install_from_packages.html#install-puppet-server

But final installation step fails with

```bash
# apt-get install puppetserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 puppetserver : Depends: puppet-agent (>= 6.16.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To me it seems that `puppetserver` package declares an unresolvable dependency on package `puppet-agent`:

```bash
# aptitude search puppet-agent
[EMPTY RESULT]
```

Package repository seems to be correct:

```bash
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppet7.list 
# Puppet 7 bullseye Repository
deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com bullseye puppet7
```

Operating on Debian 11 Bullseye:

```bash
$ cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
```

So I have no idea how to fix it on my side.
Any help/hint appreciated.

Comment: It may be that you *can't* resolve it on your side.  Have you considered [filing a ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa)?  Of course, you should probably try all the usual client-side corrective actions first (`apt-get update`, for example), but if Puppet, Inc.'s repository is really borked then not only have you no good client-side solution, but Puppet would appreciate hearing about the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, as you recommended I've opened a ticket.